# Recurrent Neural Networks: How to find the optimal parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gru

I am trying to fit a recurrent neural network for a binary classification problem using the 'keras' library (https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/). Now these networks have many parameters to tune.

LSTM

> keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM(output_dim, init='glorot_uniform',
>   inner_init='orthogonal', forget_bias_init='one', activation='tanh',
>   inner_activation='hard_sigmoid', W_regularizer=None,
>   U_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None, dropout_W=0.0, dropout_U=0.0)

GRU

> keras.layers.recurrent.GRU(output_dim, init='glorot_uniform',
>   inner_init='orthogonal', activation='tanh',
>   inner_activation='hard_sigmoid', W_regularizer=None,
>   U_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None, dropout_W=0.0, dropout_U=0.0)

Simple RNN

> keras.layers.recurrent.SimpleRNN(output_dim, init='glorot_uniform',
>   inner_init='orthogonal', activation='tanh', W_regularizer=None,
>   U_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None, dropout_W=0.0, dropout_U=0.0)

How do I tune these parameters? Which are the most important ones to tune if am selecting only few parameters to tune?

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, you usually perform a [cross validation,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) or even better, a k-fold cross validation.

The idea is the following:

1. Determine an ***error threshold***
2. Divide your samples into ***k*** subsets of the same size (without gaps, potentially overlapping)
3. Repeat until satisfactory performance is reached

   1. Select one particular combination of ***parameters*** (e.g. randomly of with a [parameter optimization approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization))
   2. Initialize an ***error sum*** with value $0 $
   3. For each subset

      1. Call this subset ***"validation set"***
      2. For each *other* subset

         1. Call this subset ***"test set"***
         2. Repeat until the model approximates the *validation subset* with an error below the *error threshold*

            1. Call all subsets ***"training set"*** that are neither *test set* nor *validation set*
            2. Train your model on the *training set* and with the chosen *parameters*
         3. Add the model's error for each *test set* to the *error sum*
   4. The error sum (divided by $k * (k - 1) $) is a measure for parameter quality: the lower the better